# how to compare all the entered values in textboxes with each other in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.ac').blur(function(evt) {
    if ($('.ac').val() > $('.tc').val()) {
        alert('ERROR ac > tc');
        evt.preventDefault();
    } 
});
```

I Wanted to compare ac and tc in the above code and i am getting it done only for the first character entered in ac box, But i need it to compare the full value entered in ac and compare it with tc. and my html. and also it should be done for all the ac boxes.

```
<form>
tc<input class="tc"/><br>
ac<input class="ac"/><br>
tc<input class="tc"/><br>
ac<input class="ac"/><br>
tc<input class="tc"/><br>
ac<input class="ac"/> <br>  
</form>
```

i have edited the following and nothings happening

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
$('.ac').change(function(evt) {
    if ($(parseInt(('.ac').val())) > $(parseInt(('.tc').val()))) {
        alert('ERROR ac > tc');
        evt.preventDefault();
    } 
});
</script>
```

Comment: you want to compare how?!

Comment: compare the values entered in ac with the entered values of tc and alert if ac > tc

Comment: i know that, give us some sample, abc > baaaaa or something like that

Comment: A numerical or lexical comparison? What about equality? Should 3 be considered greater than 1, should 1 be greater, or less, than `c`? What values are you expecting? What restrictions are in place?

Comment: example if ac=60 and tc=7 i get ac > tc as i have changed the code to grater than

Comment: if you want to compare numerical values first parse the values then compare them

Comment: i have edited and pasted the new code but nothing happend

Comment: change this if (parseInt($('.ac').val()) > parseInt($('.tc').val()))

Comment: Nothing happens because you put the 'parseint' between jquery's dollar sign and you broke the code.

Comment: Can u plz guide me where to put the parseint

Comment: use my answer below. or follow user2675751's answer above.

Comment: If you're unaware how to use the console log, instead of harassing alert boxes, just press F12 on your keyboard and you'll see it.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this HTML! I put ac and tc in pairs using a div called .box.

```
<form>
<div class="box">
    tc<input class="tc" value="10"/><br>
    ac<input class="ac"/><br>
</div>
<div class="box">
    tc<input class="tc" value="20"/><br>
    ac<input class="ac"/><br>
</div>
    <div class="box">
    tc<input class="tc" value="30"/><br>
    ac<input class="ac"/><br>
</div>
</form>
```

Then in Jquery i can without know which .ac I'm asking for box father and then for chill .tc

```
$('.ac').blur(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var ac = Number($(this).val());
    var tc = Number($(this).parents(".box").find(".tc").val());

    if (ac > tc) {
        alert('ERROR ac='+ac+' > tc='+tc);
    } else {
        alert('ERROR ac='+ac+' <= tc='+tc)
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58VqD/2/)

Reedited cuz I lost my old edition

Comment: again it only compares with the first character of tc and alerts that ac != tc but i want it to compare full character

Comment: example if ac=60 and tc=7 i get ac > tc as i have changed the code to grater than

Comment: u should parse to int before compare as numbers! Use parseInt() with both vals

Comment: know i see the problem! Are you trying to compare all ac with all tc?

Comment: Yes Mr MARC thats the problem

Comment: And u wanna do it by pairs or all with all? Can u give me 1 or 2 examples pls?

Comment: YES i am trying to do the same thing what you asked but am stuck in only get only one ac box result

Comment: Do it with pairs for each and every entries it is total classes with attended class that is what tc and ac

Comment: Are you wanting the sum of all the ac's to be compared to the sum of all the tc's or just check if any of the ac's are larger than any of the tc's?

Comment: I cant get the unique ids as the text boxes are generated dynamically for updating  multiple records to my sql

Comment: Yes, you can make them into arrays when generating dynamically

Comment: i want to check with each and every ac's with tc box not the sum of ac with tc

Comment: Can u plz guide me to do it as i am new to this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37832/discussion-between-user2774977-and-gary-hayes)

Comment: Dont forget to check for NaN after parseInt.

Comment: Dont forget to check for NaN after parseInt. what does this mean

Comment: If the input is empty then parseInt will give u NaN (not a number). But with Number NaN equals to 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$('.ac').blur(function(evt) {
var num1 = Number($('.ac').val());
var num2 = Number($('.tc').val());
 if (num1 > num2) {
        console.log('ERROR ac > tc');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});

</script>
```

Make sure you're comparing numbers and not strings that consist of numbers.

Comment: You should add a check for NaN after doing `Number($('.ac').val());`